# I was able to review audits even though I was suspended from doing so

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I got review banned for 7 days on March 3rd, 2014. I have the habit to click on Review whenever I am on Stack Overflow's page. Yesterday it was showing me the following regular message

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in **4** days to continue reviewing.

So there were 4 days left of my review ban. But this morning when I click on the Review link, it allowed me to perform a review. You can see my [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330969/kedarnath?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

> [image]

I double checked all the reviews, there isn't any failure in today's reviews.

Now again when I click on review again it shows me same message as before, but with a 3 day warning

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in **3** days to continue reviewing.

First I thought that it was because of some of my **helpful flags** that my review ban is lifted automatically by the system. But now I think that this is a bug in the system. It shouldn't allow me to review  for the next 3 days.

**Update**
This issue is re-produced with me just before few minutes. I have notice one thing that this happens only one time, meaning after ban this happens one time only and once it happens it doesnt happens again till the ban period is over.

Comment: @Animuson, you found it too fast.

Comment: Looks like a real bug. So why the downvotes ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, Different people, different thinking. They are probably downvoting because I *fail review*.

Comment: Why did you rolled back that edit? Titles shoudln't contain tags which was what him056 fixed...

Comment: One should not edit a post, which is already edit by "gnat". He is the best.

Comment: @Kedarnath I guess there was still plenty left to fix. So please don't roll it back again.

Comment: One should not add a tag name in the title. It is bad.