# I was able to review after failing an audit, but later got blocked from reviewing

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I might be just me, but it's not the first time this happens. I failed an audit yesterday (can't remember in which category) and I got the *Stop, look and listen* message.

I have no excuse whatsoever for failing the review, but I was able afterwards to continue reviewing because I have passed the previous 20-30 tests and made at least 100 previous reviews correct. I even got another "test" afterwards in *First posts* and passed it. Nevertheless, I saw this morning that I got blocked from reviewing for almost a month (minus 2 days).

I feel that this is strange, in the sense that I don't know exactly for which review I got blocked, but I'm guessing it because it is the only one failed recently. But if so, has anyone else encountered this "delay"?

**Edit:** I just looked over my activity and saw that I made 10 more reviews after failing. Furthermore, at least 6 hours passed until I got blocked from reviewing

Comment: A moderator could have manually blocked you; the block message doesn't change in that case.

Comment: @Kedarnath if that is duplicate than this a regression of that one because it has status-completed. It can't be closed as a duplicate in that case...

Comment: Even I am in same situation http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224488/252811

Comment: for more information read this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214156/252811

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have a similar problem, but i don't want to open a new question, as there are allready some for this. I can't do reviews now until `APR 26`, which is almost a month. And as much as i remember i failed 2 or 3 audit reviews in the past, and those are weeks ago. Can you please have a look at it and tell me why i have been "banned" and not only for a few days like normal? Thanks

Comment: @Kedarnath - In this question the OP was able to review after **failing an audit** not **blocked**. That means after failing an audit the OP reviewed some items and *then* he was blocked.

Comment: @Springrbua My audit also ends on April 26.

Comment: @Springrbua: I cannot; I am not a moderator and cannot see your review ban status.

Comment: @Kedarnath Your link was quite useful. I have been searching for a possible duplicate of this but wasn't able to find that

Comment: @hims056, haven't you ever failed an audit !!! There is no rule like after first audit fail you get banned. When user fails certain amount of audit fail then he/she get banned. That certain amount is un-defined. But its definitely not `1`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh i am sorry i just saw that after posting the comment.
I am just a bit surprised, cause i really always read the things, i also go to the original question/answer, to see other answers to and compare the quality. I almost always leave a comment to new users to tell them how they can improve and now for some reason i can't see i can't do that anymore. I don't think thats right...

Comment: @RaulRene thats seems long doesn't it? I have seen a few post telling "i can't review for 2 days, for 7 days" but not a month. How many audits did you fail? I failed 2 or 3, and they are weeks ago...

Comment: @Kedarnath - You still didn't get it (or may be I am misunderstanding this question). The OP was not blocked **after failing an audit**, but he was blocked *after review some stuffs*.

Comment: @Springrbua: Perhaps you need to contact the community moderators team (use the 'contact us' link) to ask for why you were blocked.

Comment: @hims056, That's what I am saying. Nobody directly gets fail like that, unless he/she has failed previous audit.

Comment: @Springrbua: I failed a couple I think 2 months ago, and got blocked for 7 days. Since then, as I posted, I passed some 20-30 audits and reviewed more than 100 posts (I'm pretty sure it's more than 200). I thought that after some time and by passing other "tests" the system kinda forgets you for the ones failed before

Comment: @RaulRene the number of passes or successful reviews may or may not factor into the ban as I don't recall seeing that info published, but the bans are incremental within [a 30-day window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562/182513)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Wow, that answer is really helpful. I was guessing that it's something like that but thought that it's a more complicated algorithm

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah yea ofc i could try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Springrbua Moderators can issue review bans manually, and in that case they don't always follow the same escalation rules as automatic bans. Passing audits doesn't guarantee that you won't get banned, especially with suggested edits where audits can be detected easily. SO moderators sometimes issue review bans to users who approved suggested edits that introduce spam, for example.

Comment: @Gilles I can't approve suggested edits as i don't have enough reputation. And i really don't think (and hope), that it was a moderator, because i really try to help with my reviews. I don't do it for the badge, like a few other people. I contacted the mods and hope for a soon answer and then i will see. I ll let you know.

Comment: You can get manually banned from reviewing for repeatedly doing bad reviews. Regardless of whether it's an audit or not. Someone posts an answer saying "I also have this problem, what is solution?" and you say 'No Action Needed', even if that's not an audit it is still A Bad Review. Moderators will block you from doing more if you robo-review things like that.

Comment: @JonW: I agree, and I knew this. However, I would like to know (if it'possible) the exact reason for which I got the temporary blocking for reviews. 
It's a little bit annoying to not know, because there's a chance it's something subjective, or at least if you know what you got wrong you can improve in the future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alright, I reopened this because it isn't really a duplicate of the questions people thought it was.

I was the one who manually banned you from review. I did so because you approved obvious spam: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4356893 which allowed that spam to linger on this site for weeks. I normally ban reviewers that do this for 30 days, because you're causing active harm to the site when you do this.

The post content is as follows (for those who can't see deleted answers, as image so their spam link doesn't click through):

[image: Image of spam]

Additionally, you've been banned from review 10 times before this, so 30 days is a minimum ban that I would give someone repeatedly showing a degree of carelessness in reviews.

I also banned a bunch of other people who approved **10** instances of spam on this one off topic question alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825462/migration-from-thunderbird-to-outlook . Let me tell you, I was a little pissed to see that. All of them were banned for 30 days.

When you are able to review again, please be extremely careful when reviewing anything in the Late Answers or First Posts queue. There have been many instances of spam slipping through review there lately, and anyone I find doing this is getting banned from review, passed audits or no.

Comment: This was the answer I was expecting for. I am curious to see how the spammed post looked, because it doesn't appear anymore.
I guess what I wanted to say with this post is that showing the reason for a "review ban" would be something helpful.

Comment: @RaulRene - I added the post content. We do need a better way of annotating this in the review ban message, as it makes manual bans look like you failed audits. It doesn't help for educational purposes, since you would have never seen this review in your history once the answer was deleted as spam. This came up here, as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226641/learning-from-the-mistakes-that-led-to-a-review-ban/226643#comment742097_226643

Comment: I dumped a bounty on this feature request for just this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196176/could-we-make-the-review-banned-by-a-mod-notice-say-something-more-descriptive in order to give it a little more visibility.