# Return after brief hiatus to find I have a review ban

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I didn't visit SO for last 2 days. When I come today and try to access review queue it says

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back on Apr 26 at 22:10 to continue reviewing.

I just checked my reviews, I passed all the recent reviews. What is the solution of this?

Comment: You might have been manually review banned by a moderator -- it's stupid, but it still shows the same message if you've been manually banned. Have you ever been review banned before?

Comment: Why that happen?? I don't know what I've done? :S

Comment: Usually, moderators only review ban users where they do not take action on posts that aren't answers that are posted as one, spam, offensive, gibberish or absolutely horrible posts in general.

Comment: Well I don't think I did anything like this. Is there any solution?

Comment: You'd have to wait for a moderator to elaborate, though make sure to check through your recent reviews to make sure you haven't done so by accident ([First Posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history)/[Late Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history)). Note that people with less than 10k cannot see the full review history, except for their own reviews.

Comment: Why downvote? I suggest that if anybody downvote a question please comment the reason.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy >> Guess I've to wait. :(

Comment: @rashad Looking through the first two pages of your review history, http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4434631 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4434531 look a bit questionable to me, IMHO.

Answer (score 21):

I banned you from review for 30 days for approving this spam: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4381230 . I describe more about this in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227071/i-was-able-to-review-after-failing-an-audit-but-later-got-blocked-from-reviewin/227105#227105).

For reference, this was the review in question:

[image]

All of the reviewers that approved the 10 instances of spam there were banned from review, if they had not already been banned by the system. When you are reviewing Late Answers, you have one primary responsibility, and that's to flag any spam you see. Approving spam harms the site by letting it live, and I ban anyone I catch doing this.

Additionally, you had a few other questionable reviews that I saw, and had been banned by the system once already, so I felt 30 days was appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, that was at the beginning when I could access review queue. I  learned a good lesson though. in addition I can't see the answer for that I've been blocked. :(

Comment: @Rashad - I've added an image of the answer that was the problem here. It's clearly an advertisement for a commercial product. Be very skeptical of short answers by new users to old questions that talk positively about a product and include a link. This particular user was part of a larger network spamming these products across the site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be more careful. Hope I will not forget it within 1 month.. :P

Comment: By the way can you change the message that SO showing me. I've been banned manually. The message is confusing.

Comment: @Rashad - I agree, and it's why I posted a bounty to bring more attention to this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196176/could-we-make-the-review-banned-by-a-mod-notice-say-something-more-descriptive . We need to have a better way of letting people know about this, rather than having them need to ask about it on Meta.

Comment: It feels sad though, but thanks.. :)